# How to get current running job and user which is triggered that job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have an requirement that same user cannot trigger the same job twice when the same job is in running state.
How do i get the details of current running job and user which is triggered that job in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to that, or any plugin which can be used for that - and I know a lot :-)

The only way I see is to write your own plugin.